# Bubble sort homework not adding to dictionary

Tags: python

So for my homework I need to create the function `bubblesort`, which bubble sorts a list of numbers and returns a dictionary with the state of the number list after each pass, and then the sorted list. I can't seem to get the dictionary to work even though when I print out the values in the same line they work.

Attached is the code with the doctests

```
def bubbleSort(numList):
    '''
        Takes a list and returns 2 values
        1st returned value: a dictionary with the state of the list after each complete pass of bubble sort
        2nd returned value: the sorted list

        >>> bubbleSort([9,3,5,4,1,67,78])
        ({1: [3, 5, 4, 1, 9, 67, 78], 2: [3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 67, 78], 3: [3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78], 4: [1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78], 5: [1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78]}, [1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 67, 78])
    '''
    # initialization of dictionary and loop counter
    bubble_dict = {}
    num_loop = 0
    # for loop that resets swapped to False and adds 1 to num_loop
    for i in range(len(numList) - 1):
        swapped = False
        num_loop += 1
        # runs through the list index, swaps index with index+1 if appropriate
        for j in range(len(numList) - 1):
            if numList[j] > numList[j+1]:
                temp = numList[j]
                numList[j] = numList[j+1]
                numList[j+1] = temp
                swapped = True
        # Everything works up to adding to the dictionary, even printouts
        # of num_loop and numList
        print(num_loop, numList)
        bubble_dict[num_loop] = numList
        if not swapped:
            break

    return bubble_dict, numList
```

Comment: You probably want: `bubble_dict[num_loop] = numList[:]`

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "can't get the dictionary to work"?

Comment: [on ideone](https://ideone.com/MXzpZM) it works fine, show more code, probably the problem is somewhere else

Comment: adding bubble_dict[num_loop] = numList[:] solved it!

Comment: btw, for a more complete question you should have included the current output and a note about why it is wrong. Also do you understand why my fix worked?